# Custom Post Type Wordpress for user create only one item

Tags: php, wordpress

I created a basic post type item with the name "Public Adjusters", the new user "Subscriber" will be able to create only one item(Public Adjusters) in this post type, so it will appear in the menu only "my item" where it can directly edit this item. I am using the post type ui plugin wordpress.

```
/**
     * Post Type: Public Adjusters.
     */

    $labels = array(
        "name" => __( "Public Adjusters", "" ),
        "singular_name" => __( "Public Adjuster", "" ),
        "menu_name" => __( "Public Adjusters", "" ),
        "all_items" => __( "All Public Adjusters", "" ),
        "add_new" => __( "Add New", "" ),
        "add_new_item" => __( "Add New Public Adjuster", "" ),
        "edit_item" => __( "Edit Public Adjuster", "" ),
        "new_item" => __( "New Public Adjuster", "" ),
        "view_item" => __( "View Public Adjuster", "" ),
        "view_items" => __( "View Public Adjusters", "" ),
        "search_items" => __( "Search Public Adjusters", "" ),
        "not_found" => __( "No Public Adjusters Found", "" ),
        "not_found_in_trash" => __( "No Public Adjusters found in trash", "" ),
        "parent_item_colon" => __( "Parent Public Adjuster", "" ),
        "featured_image" => __( "Featured Image", "" ),
        "set_featured_image" => __( "Set Featured Image", "" ),
        "remove_featured_image" => __( "Remove Featured Image", "" ),
        "use_featured_image" => __( "Use Featured Image", "" ),
        "archives" => __( "Archives", "" ),
        "insert_into_item" => __( "Insert into Public Adjuster", "" ),
        "uploaded_to_this_item" => __( "Uploaded to this Item Public Adjuster", "" ),
        "filter_items_list" => __( "Filter Public Adjusters List", "" ),
        "items_list_navigation" => __( "Public Adjuster List Navigation", "" ),
        "items_list" => __( "Public Adjusters List", "" ),
        "attributes" => __( "Public Adjuster Attribute", "" ),
        "parent_item_colon" => __( "Parent Public Adjuster", "" ),
    );

    $args = array(
        "label" => __( "Public Adjusters", "" ),
        "labels" => $labels,
        "description" => "",
        "public" => true,
        "publicly_queryable" => true,
        "show_ui" => true,
        "show_in_rest" => false,
        "rest_base" => "",
        "has_archive" => false,
        "show_in_menu" => true,
        "show_in_nav_menus" => true,
        "exclude_from_search" => false,
        "capability_type" => "post",
        "map_meta_cap" => true,
        "hierarchical" => false,
        "rewrite" => array( "slug" => "public_adjusters", "with_front" => true ),
        "query_var" => true,
        "supports" => array( "title" ),
        "taxonomies" => array( "category", "locations" ),
    );

    register_post_type( "public_adjusters", $args );
```

Comment: The question is confusing.  What are you asking how to do? To make it so the user can add _only one_ of this post type?  If so, WP doesn't have a built-in way to limit the number of posts for a given post type, AFAIK - but I've marked this question as duplicate of another that has an anwer that should work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Limit number of custom post type posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33107457/limit-number-of-custom-post-type-posts)

Comment: yes currently the user can create as many items as he wants, it has to be limited to create only one item. And in the menu show just "Edit your Item"